# Not generating .cpi file in Corda5

Tags: corda, corda-dlt

```
I am trying to run corda 5, but getting error "corda5-obligation-cordapp/workflows/build/corda5-obligation-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.cpi (No such file or directory)" while running 5-vNodeSetup step  after already sunning "startCorda" for "corda5-obligation-cordapp" project and "bootcamp-cordapp" branch. It is giving the understanding of not able to create .cpi file which is essential for generating nodes.
GroupPolicy.json is giving the error: Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.corda.cli.application.BootKt
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/corda/cli/application/BootKt has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0


 Please suggest what am I  missing. 


  Even corda-cli installer in java-11 is giving error for command- corda-cli.sh -h
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.corda.cli.application.BootKt
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/corda/cli/application/BootKt has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0. Corda-cli runs for java-17. #corda #corda5
```

I am not able to generate .cpi files under workflows

Answer (score 0):

@Mrinmoyee Mandal Looks like your classes were compiled using JDK17.The class version 61 is the class version of Java 17. Check the compiler set in your IDE. Use JDK11 as compiler.